# Bluez bluetoothd requires root for all processes interacting with it

Tags: ubuntu, root, bluetooth, d-bus, bluez

I've upgraded my bluez installation to version 5.41 on my Ubuntu xenail box (16.04). I'm trying to do some testing with a piece of bluetooth low energy hardware so I'm staring bluetoothd with the following command from the command line to enable the experimental GATT interface.

```
sudo bluetoothd -E
```

My problem is that after upgrading, I now have to run as root to use bluetoothctl utility or the interact with the dbus interface (via d-feet). If I try to use the (list show or power on) commands in bluetoothctl I'm informed that there is *"No default controller available"*, if I try to issue a start discovery command via d-feet on /org/bluez/hci0 i get a *org.freedesktop.Dbus.Error.AcccessDenied* error. I did not have this problem with the default installation.

I didn't find much in the way of installation instructions for bluez so I just went about it the standard way (via the commands below). I think I also had to make a symlink to bluetoothd so it was on my path.

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

So I'm wondering what I can do to adjust the permissions for bluetoothd so that I can access bluetooth api from process not running as root.

Thanks